# CSS - Select childs that are the first after line break

Tags: css, css-selectors

Let's assume I have a `div` wrapper, with several elements inside, placed as `inline`. When the div's width is reduced, the elements will automatically break down to new lines... So far so good.

Now I want to add a css `:before` content to the child elements, **except on the ones that are the first on the line**...

Is there a way to detect, css only, if the element is the first one after the line break?

**EDIT**

Follows up an example... http://jsfiddle.net/kagfqt9j/

The div's width caused the children to be broken in three lines. There's a "|" divider set with `:before`. But I don't want the `:before` to be applied on the begining of the lines.

So, can I detect the first element after break?

Note: Changing it to `:after` is not a solution, because it would invert the problem... Then I would have the "|" at the end of the lines... And I can't have it either.

Comment: There may be a solution if you could provide a simplified example on an [online editor](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your fiddle is your real situation, container with `overflow:hidden` and `text-align left`: then , you may use this to set outside the container the pseudo with a negative margin: http://jsfiddle.net/kagfqt9j/1/

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right:0.25em;
    text-decoration:none;/* demo purpose */
}

 a:before {
    content: "| ";/* extra white-space aside the pipe */
    margin-left:-0.25em;
    color:black;/* demo purpose */
    pointer-events:none;/* demo purpose */
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. I came up with a similar solution, but I've added an inner div, misplaced it to the left to hide the "pipes", and added a margin to the `:first-child`. Figured that there's no way to do it with a selector... Anyway, your solution is cleaner, and this "hack" is acceptable for me. I'm marking you as right answer.

Comment: Great!, you are welcome, i did not expect this situation to be the real one, seemed too simple to be true :)

Answer (score 2):

JS solution

```js
var lastOffsetTop = -1;
var elements = document.querySelector('.something');

for (var i = 0; i < elemenrs.length; i++)
{
  if (elements[i].offsetTop != lastOffsetTop)
    Sys.UI.DomElement.addCssClass(elements[i], 'firstInLine');
  else
    Sys.UI.DomElement.removeCssClass(elements[i], 'firstInLine');

  lastOffsetTop = elemens.offsetTop;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible using CSS.

Using Javascript/JQuery, you could find the offset/location of each element and then determine which one is to the very left in the parent div.